# Media download return whatsapp api url

Tags: laravel, whatsapp-cloud-api

I would like to know what the type of return of the image is, because when I use an application like insomnia it returns the image itself and as I am programming it in laravel to be able to save it in the database I need to know what its return is exactly because how the information comes from the webhook I don't have a screen to try to display the callback, so I would like to know if someone can help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did not understand the question

Comment: As I'm a newbie I might end up leaving something out but here it is saying
content-digest adler32=1433317828
etag 6652693148250777238
x-manifold-obj-blobsizebytes 16767
x-manifold-obj-canonicalpath flat/665888922265021
x-manifold-obj-ctime 1691520964
x-manifold-obj-entrytype 1
x-manifold-obj-expiresat 0
x-manifold-obj-propertiesjson {"blob_state":"created","__ctime":"1691520963"}
x-manifold-obj-symlinktarget
cross-origin-resource-policy cross-origin
accept-ranges bytes
content-length 16239
content-disposition inline;filename=File.jpg
content-type image/jpeg

Comment: In this case it would be a return of a list of int?

Comment: In this case I'm receiving the information in laravel and I'm going to save the postgresql image so I have to configure the return to put it inside